Generic Function which guarantees a key of specific type
I'm trying to implement a generic sort, which does 2 things.
It takes an array of type T, that must have atleast one key with the specified type(string in this example), and an key from T without specifying which key it in the function body is(imagine multiple properties with string values, i should be able to pass any of them). It should not show intellisense for the properties that does not match the the Filter Criteria. However I can't quite get right. Either I end up with a type missmatch on the callers side(as example is showing). Or i end up with a function body that is of type any, such is the case if i replace [name: string]: name with[name: string]: any. Or I'am forced to name the specific key that i want to use for sorting(which I don't really wanna do as that removes the reusability). as is the case for T extends {name: string}
This is what has been closest to working:
type User = {
  name: string;
  lastName?: string
  age: number
}
const myUsers: User[] = [{age: 32, name: "Foo"}]

type FilterBy<T, U> = {
  [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends U ? Key : never]: T[Key];
};

type InferValueFromArray<T extends any[]> = T extends Array<infer R>
  ? R
  : never;

const sortingBy = <T extends { [name: string]: string | undefined }[], K extends keyof FilterBy<InferValueFromArray<T>, string|undefined>>(data: T, key: K) => {
  return data.sort((a, b) => (a[key] || '').localeCompare(b[key] || ''));
};

// this errors as Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
const mySortedUsers = sortingBy(myUsers, 'lastName');

Here is the TS Playground Link

• Why is the second type parameter to FilterBy called K? That letter is conventionally used to indicate keylike types. If I were you I would use U (which is "the next thing after T" conventionally in a way that K is decidedly not) or V (for "value" which makes more sense here). Could you [edit] to do that so it's not distracting from the question? Also, there's no link in your question, despite the last line. • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Ohh i never realized there was a convention for this, guess i know now for the future. I've updated my answer!
What i'm missing in relation to your answer is that I don't really want keys that aren't able to be used, to be shown at all.

By "shown at all" I presume you're talking about autosuggestions/autocompletions in IntelliSense, right? If that matters, can you make sure to [edit] the question to specify this?  If you need that also you can use both approaches at once as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs now? (Note that I think maaaaybe I've answered a question exactly like this before so it's possible I'll find it and close as a duplicate instead of writing an answer.) If not, what's still missing?

Yes, thanks alot @jcalz!! Could not wrap my head around how to solve this, did some really funky stuff trying to figure it out! Would love if you could find the previous answer, as i tried to search around for a while before posting but to no avail.

Okay, I found related question/answers above. The first one is very very similar although it doesn't allow optional properties (and I just added ? in the constraint to allow that).
